# Tally of fake hate crimes?

Tags: united-states, statistics, crime, discrimination

Is there a tally of fake [hate crimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hate_crime_laws_in_the_United_States) in the United States, by year, with ideological identification?  I'm defining a fake hate crime as any incident where one:

- defaces, destroys or vandalizes a public space, building, car, etc. with graffiti
- lies about an assault, attack, or racist or derogatory speech directed at themsevles
- plants racist, misogynistic, or anti-religious symbols

with the aim of using [deception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag) to marginalize political or cultural enemies, or to garner sympathy for a cause or group.

For example,  I would consider this a fake hate crime:

> Police say [liberal student activist](http://www.campusreform.org/?ID=4731&CFID=9082762&CFTOKEN=66363745) threatened herself with rape in Facebook hoax, framed conservatives

But [this](http://www.sanluisobispo.com/news/local/article48085445.html#storylink=cpy) is a real one:

> Cal Poly student arrested in connection with death threat against SLO Solidarity leader

There is a fakehatecrime.org website that doesn't look legit to me, FYI.  You have to join, and quite honestly, I didn't feel comfortable giving them my info.  So if you know more about the site or if your mileage varies, let me know.

Comment: I doubt that one exists, as it is hard to track (especially as you go back in history).  I looked around that site and while I wouldn't necessarily use the word "garbage," it is riddled with inconsistencies, flimsy reporting, and lack of clarity.

Comment: Good luck. It's hard to imagine how you would even collect these statistics. We can collect stats on actual hate crimes because they result in a conviction, by tracking journal entries from the courts we can track the crimes. But what do you track for fake crimes?

Comment: @indigochild. The news. Also it's illegal to file false police reports.

Comment: @KDog - It's up to the courts to decide what is a fake report. The news wouldn't be a good source of evidence. You probably could look for stats on false allegations, I know the FBI has something there, but it may not get you what you want.

Comment: This is not really about politics though.  Its kind of tangental but not about politics.

Comment: Would you count real crimes that were wrongly claimed to be hate crimes?

Comment: @gnasher729. No, for example during the Bill Clinton Era there was a rash of black church burnings that were reported as hate crimes. Turned out to be an arsonist burning black and white churches but the press only picked up on the black ones.

Comment: @KDog, re *"rash of ... church burnings..."*: wouldn't that be a case of journalists having *misattributed* a motive for arson, rather than a *fake*?  Misattributions might be more common than actual fakes.

Comment: @agc  Yes.  Isn't that what Ghasher said?  Real crimes that were wrongly claimed to be hate crimes.  Don't think they fit the bill.

Comment: @KDog, You're right, (I'd misunderstood your example), my apologies.

Comment: I love the fact that there's so much fakery around there are fake tallies of  fake crimes

Comment: @indigochild:  The problem with tracking the FBI statisitics is that hate crimes are not crimes in and of themselves... there has to be an actual criminal attack and evidence that it was motivated in part or in whole by hatred of a protected class.  They are also usually federal crimes but the underlying crime is investigated by local police forces, who may not notify the FBI if they identify that race was an component factor early on.

Comment: @indigochild:  I'm not saying don't use the FBI and other government sources, I'm just saying do not use them exclusively.  Some of these reports could be a media narrative driven accusation, not a prosecutorial driven.  fakehate.org doesn't track the rate of fake accusations vs. real accusations either... which I would like to see in reporting.

Comment: @KDog Series of church burnings quite likely was still a hate crime. Simply on religious instead of ethnic grounds, so it's still real hate crime.